# Check mongoose for 2 fields before saving user (with passportjs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm using passportjs in my express app, and I've just implemented the code that checks mongoDB to see if 'email' or 'businessName' are already registered. My code is mostly working so I'm only going to provide the part of it I think is necessary.

```
 User.findOne({
            $or: [
              { username: { $regex: req.body.username, $options: "i" } },
              {
                businessName: { $regex: req.body.businessName, $options: "i" },
              },
            ],
          }).then((person) => {
            // email or businessName already exist
            if (person) {
              res.render("signup", {
                exists: "This email is already registered",
                info: req.body,
                errors: errorsObj,
                msg: "Please check the form for errorsss",
              });
            } else {
              const user = new User({
                businessName: req.body.businessName,
                username: req.body.username,
                password: theHash,
              });
              user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  return next(err);
                }
                //succesful - redirect to login
                res.redirect("/login");
              });
            }
          });
```

As you can see I search for 2 fields, and use the 'exists' variable to render the error message to my ejs. However I would like to be able to display 2 separate messages, one for if a 'username' already exists, and one for if a 'businessName' already exists. I've also tried to set it up so I do 2 separate searches, one for 'username' and one for 'businessName', but I feel like if I can avoid calling an extra search that'd be good.

Answer (score 1):

}).then((person) => {

```
if ( person.username === req.body.username ){
   //render username message
}
if ( businessName ===  person.businessName ) {
   //render busniness name message
}
```